# Help with Improving Performance of SQL Server 2008 CTE

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, sql-execution-plan

I have a SQL Server 2008 CTE which is responsible for returning the **Top Review** for a location.

The CTE is wrapped in a UDF (Table-Valued), and joined on the *LocationId* field, so i can get the top review for each location.

**Cardinalities**:

**1** Location has **0-many** PostLocations

**1** PostLocation has **1** Post

**1** Post has **1** Review

Here's the UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Review_HighestRated_Aggregated_ByLocation]
(   

)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH [RankedLocations] AS
    (
        SELECT      PL.LocationId, 
                    R.Rating, 
                    P.PostID, 
                    P.UniqueUri, 
                    P.Content, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PL.LocationId ORDER BY R.Rating DESC, P.LocationTypeId, P.CreatedOn DESC) As ScoreRank

        From        dbo.PostLocations As PL
        INNER JOIN  dbo.Posts As P
        ON          P.PostId = PL.PostId
        INNER JOIN  dbo.Reviews As R
        ON          R.PostId = P.PostId

        WHERE       R.ReviewTypeId <> 5
        AND         P.Content IS NOT NULL
    )

    SELECT  LocationId, Rating, PostID, UniqueUri, Content
    FROM    RankedLocations
    WHERE   ScoreRank = 1
)
```

Here's an example of how i'm using it:

```
select l.LocationId, l.Name, l.UniqueUri, r.UniqueUri, r.Content
from @Locations l -- temp table containing around 18 location ids
inner join dbo.Review_HighestRated_Aggregated_ByLocation() r 
on l.LocationId = r.LocationId
```

The above query is taking **15 seconds** to execute, which is unacceptable. Without the join to the UDF it's takes 0 seconds.

Any ideas on how i can improve it?

If i look at the execution plan, it's the **SORT** that is taking up 98% of the execution cost. The IO/subtree cost of this operation is ~300.

I was hoping the execution plan would give me a hint to an index i could create to improve the cost, but i get nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there an index on `R.ReviewTypeId` ?? Do you have indices on the columns used for foreign key relationships (`PostId` in the three tables)? Also: another option would be to try to use the CTE in your query directly, instead of "hiding" it inside the UDF (which can be notoriously slow...) - does that make any difference??

Comment: @marc_s. Yes there is an index on ReviewTypeId. Yes, PostId is a clustered PK on Posts, part of the clustered PK on PostLocations, and clustered PK on Reviews. I also tried using the CTE directly, no change. I've tried to create a View, which is fine - but you can't index a View that has aggregate operations in it, or subquery's. At the moment i'm leaning towards a "cache table" that get's updated every hour or so with a sql scheduled job. thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found the performance problem, and it wasn't the CTE, it was how i was using it.

I have several lookup tables, one in particular for Location Type (Street = 7, City = 5, etc).

So to keep my SQL fluent and consistent (and avoid hard-coded magic numbers), i created a wrapper scalar function which returns the evuivalent value based on the string, e.g:

```
DECLARE @Street_LocationType = [dbo].[ToLocationTypeId]('Street')
```

The function is extremely simple, just a series of CASE statements.

But, i was using my CTE like this:

```
SELECT      a.LocationId, b.Content, b.UniqueUri
FROM        [dbo].[Locations] a
INNER JOIN  dbo.Review_HighestRated_Aggregated_ByLocation()  b -- UDF with CTE
ON          a.LocationId = b.LocationId        
WHERE       a.LocationTypeId = @Street_LocationType
```

So i wasn't even using it on the CTE itself, i was using it as a filter on the Locations table.

If i change the above to hardcode the value (e.g 7), the procedure execution time drops from 13 seconds to 2 secs.

I don't get it, but it solved the problem. I was noticing when the procedure was performing badly, the "SORT" operation in the query plan had an estimated number of rows = 32,000 - which is basically every post in the system.

After my changes, the estimated number of rows is 1 (as it should be).

Bizarre activity indeed.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the CTE and the UDF into a VIEW:

```
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[Review_HighestRated_Aggregated_ByLocation]
GO

CREATE VIEW Review_HighestRated_Aggregated_ByLocation
AS
SELECT  LocationId, Rating, PostID, UniqueUri, Content
FROM
(
    SELECT      PL.LocationId, 
                R.Rating, 
                P.PostID, 
                P.UniqueUri, 
                P.Content, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PL.LocationId ORDER BY R.Rating DESC, P.LocationTypeId, P.CreatedOn DESC) As ScoreRank
    From        dbo.PostLocations As PL
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Posts As P
    ON          P.PostId = PL.PostId
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Reviews As R
    ON          R.PostId = P.PostId
    WHERE       R.ReviewTypeId <> 5
    AND         P.Content IS NOT NULL
) RankedLocations
WHERE   ScoreRank = 1

GO
```

OP's sample query revised to use the new VIEW:

```
select l.LocationId, l.Name, l.UniqueUri, r.UniqueUri, r.Content
from @Locations l -- temp table containing around 18 location ids
inner join Review_HighestRated_Aggregated_ByLocation r 
on l.LocationId = r.LocationId
```

Comment: Converting the UDF into a View would help if you need to reuse the code inside the UDF.

Comment: nope, made no difference.  i think pcrofe's idea would work if i could figure out how to get rid of the CTE and thus make it an indexable view.

Answer (score 0):

If your table valued function dont need parameters consider to use a `VIEW` instead a UDF. Probably it solves the performance problem.

Comment: making it a view makes no difference. and you can't index a view that has a CTE.

Comment: i tried changing the CTE to a subselect instead, but you can't index a view with a subselect either. any ideas of how i can write that UDF as an indexable view?